# Laravel inconsistent redirect behavior

Tags: php, laravel, http, redirect

I think this might be an issue within the Laravel code, but maybe my expectations are not correct, but how Laravel handles the redirect response methods seems not consistent to me.

```
    $router->put('check', function (\Illuminate\Http\Request $request) {
        return redirect('/');
    });

    $router->put('/', function (\Illuminate\Http\Request $request) {
        echo 'PUT';
    });

    $router->get('/', function (\Illuminate\Http\Request $request) {
        echo 'GET';
    });
```

When using a "native" HTTP PUT request (eg using CURL) I will be redirected to the main page (/) with a PUT request, while if using a HTTP POST request with a "_method=put" parameter (which is resolved as a PUT request within the Laravel framework) I'm redirected with a GET request. Do I expect something wrong or is this an issue within Laravel? 
I'm using the Laravel Framework Version 5.2.

Comment: I had a similar issue but can't recall how it ended. It was something like laravel was sending a post with the attribute method put and then redirecting. Do var_dump($_SERVER) and check the requests method that way.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that my expectations regarding the HTTP client behavior were wrong. Some clients forcing the initially HTTP method for a redirect. Curl forcing the initially HTTP method also for redirection when using the -X parameter.

See [sisves](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/13892) comment on github

```
curl -L --data="_method="PUT"`
Issues a POST (since you've sending data), Laravel sees a PUT, and curl uses a GET for redirection.

curl -L -X POST --data "_method=PUT"
Same as above, but you force the redirection to use POST.

curl -L -X PUT
Issues a PUT, and forces a PUT for redirection.
```